# How do I make a shell scripted automated and read current time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a pretty important question, I have been a fan of the stegosaurus of cowsay(the package) that reads fortunes, input, etc.. So naturally it was of great importance to me to have this majestic creature tell me what day it is every day. I made the following script to do so using user input:

```
#!/bin/bash

selection=
until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do
        echo ""
        echo "PROGRAM MENU"
        echo "1 - It's Monday!"
        echo "2 - It's Tuesday!"
        echo "3 - It's Wednesday!"
        echo "4 - It's Thursday!"
        echo "5 - It's Friday!"
        echo "6 - Custom input"
        echo "7 - Exit"
        echo ""
        echo -n "Enter selection: "
        read selection
        echo ""
        case $selection in
                1 ) cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's Monday!"
                 exit ;;
                2 ) cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's Tuesday!"
                 exit ;;
                3 ) cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's Wednesday!"
                 exit ;;
                4 ) cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's Thursday!"
                 exit ;;
                5 ) cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's Friday!"
                 exit ;;
                6 ) echo -n "custom input > "
                 read custom
                 cowsay -f stegosaurus "$custom"
                 exit ;;
                7 ) exit ;;
                * ) cowsay -f stegosaurus "Guess what day it is?"
                 exit ;;
        esac
done
```

However, this was one of my first scripts on a linux distrobution and I'm ready to enhance my creation by making it automatically update with the current day (Maybe even hour if I can). However, I haven't been able to do this so far.. Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction?

I'd be incredibly grateful for any advice, thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I'm favoriting this question just so I can install cowsay and hear how stegosaurus sounds like!

Comment: @Shahbaz It's glorious. It fulfills that deep need to have a stegosaurus wearing a hat read you trivial text that you have been waiting all your life for. :)

Comment: consider reading `man date`

Comment: Look into the `select` command, which you are reimplementing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's $(date +%A)"
```

Check out the [GNU date documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation) for more examples of how you can format times.  e.g.

```
cowsay -f stegosaurus "It's $(date +%A) and the time is $(date +%r)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to replace:

```
read selection
```

...with:

```
selection=`date +'%u'`
```

The `date` utility, combined with the `+'FORMAT'` argument, outputs various date elements / formats. The `%u` formatting symbol translates to

> day of week (1..7); 1 represents Monday

The full doc is here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_date.htm

Bear in mind, this also means that the `* )` case scenario no longer applies.

Note: The other answer -- `"It's $(date +%A)"` -- is perfect if you wish to have the output simply be "It's [day of week]!" -- only use this answer if you want to retain custom handling for any specific days of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Try date command:

```bsh
$ date +%A
Wednesday
```